# Why is this derivation of the unit step function in the Z-domain valid?

Tags: control-system

[This source](http://www.ele.uri.edu/Courses/ele541/tutorials/ztransforms/commonfunctions.html) states that the unit step function in the Z-domain is \$\frac{z}{z-1}\$. However, in its derivation it states \$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^{-k} = \frac{z}{z-1}\$.

But doesn't that last relation only hold true for \$z>1\$? I don't see how that condition is met. I know that the poles have to be in the unit circle for the system to be stable, but I don't see if and how that connects to the condition above.

What am I missing?

Comment: This question is better asked on the [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) as you're asking about a mathematical concept and nothing electrical engineering related... or at least you haven't told us exactly _what_ your system is...

Comment: Maybe you're right, I'll post it there.

Comment: You may want to view this from 3blue1brown on the [Riemann zeta function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw).

Comment: A pole on the unit circle indicates critical stability, and a unit step sequence *is* critically stable, in the sense that it neither increases nor decreases.

Comment: @Chu I like your answer, but more specifically a *real* pole on the unit circle, which by itself can only exist at *z =1*

Comment: @Chu, I understand that, but that doesn't answer my question why the convergence can be used in the proof if it only holds for if z>1.

Comment: The infinite series obtained by dividing z by (z-1) only converges if z>1. This doesn't mean that the *pole* must be >1.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that still doesn't the answer my question. I think the answer is closer to a comment on Math.sx which basically says the function can be continued outside the range where it is defined, similarly to what is described in the @jonk 's link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to look at it.

If you consider your derived expression as a transfer function in *z* $$\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\frac{z}{z-1}$$

you can rewrite in terms of the delay operator (1/*z*) as

$$\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}$$

then cross multiply to get the difference equation
$$y(k)-y(k-1)=x(k)$$
or
$$y(k)=x(k)+y(k-1)$$
To get the impulse response *x(k)=1* for *k=0* but zero for *k >0*

from which *y(k)=1* for *k>=0*, zero elesewhere, aka the step function.

Comment: This is certainly conceptually helpful in general, but still I don't think this answers the question of why the convergence can be used in the proof if it only holds for if z>1.